# Fastest way to check for duplicates while processing an import in T-SQL

Tags: performance, t-sql, if-statement, duplicates, row-number

Looking for the fastest way to check for duplicates while processing an import in SQL.
For the most part there will be no duplicates.  I am using an IF so that ROW OVER PARTITION will only run when there are duplicates.  The IF also dumps the errors to a table.

The issue I am having is I can't use temp tables because it cannot be the same table for both IF and ELSE.

I decided to duplicate the merge for the IF and ELSE.  Is there a better/faster way to accomplish this?

```
    --@ImportID is pulled from the filename and datetime

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [#Duplicate];
    SELECT [IDColumn],
           COUNT(*) AS [Count]
    INTO [#Duplicate]
    FROM [TableOfImport]
    GROUP BY [IDColumn]
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

    --SELECT * INTO [#Unique] FROM (
    IF 0 = (SELECT MAX(count) FROM [#Duplicate])

        PRINT 'Unique'

        SELECT  *
        --INTO #UniqueInfo
        FROM  [TableOfImport]
        
        -- MERGE STATEMENT HERE --

    ELSE
        PRINT 'Duplicates'

        INSERT INTO [#error] ([Import]
                            , [Row]
                            , [Error])
        SELECT @ImportID
             , [IDColumn]
             , 'Duplicate'
          FROM [#Duplicate];

        SELECT  *
        --INTO #UniqueInfo
        FROM    (
                SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [IDColumn] ORDER BY [IDColumn] DESC) rn
                FROM    [TableOfImport]
                ) x
        WHERE   x.rn = 1

        -- SAME MERGE STATEMENT HERE --

    END
    --)
```

Comment: Well it seems to me you could probably get rid of the IF statement and do it in two steps. First, using the query you already have using the ROW_NUMBER() function insert rows into your #UniqueInfo table for all rows with an RN=1.  Step 2, using the same query insert rows into the #errors table for all rows with RN > 1.

Comment: I believe that's what I will end up doing. Was just hoping I could find a way to only run the ROW_NUMBER when there are duplicates. Or finding another fast way of doing it.